# Is it available to pass interruption-level (iOS) through firebase cloud message?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Trying to send push notification throug FCM using
`POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Is a way to send `interruption-level` to `aps` on push notification?

Comment: Any update on this? This is a very important topic!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HTTP API spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) you can provide the APNS payload via `apns` key in JSON with the appropriate values:

```json
{
  "apns": {
    "payload": {
       "aps": {
          "interruption-level": "active"
       }
       ... other APNS-specific keys such as alert, title
    }
 },
 ... your other keys such as targeting
}
```

Note that for some `interruption-level` values to work (`critical` or `time-sensitive`) you need to have the app signed with the correct entitlements.

Comment: I've try this but I'm not sure it doesn't work for me

Comment: I just have enabled `Time Sensitive Notifications` in Xcode, and added `"interruption-level": "time-sensitive"` in `aps` section, and still i don't get the notification when focus is On. Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score -1):

`fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` doens't support interruption-level. You should move to [Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=ar#node.js)