# Sending "time-sensitive" Push via Postman using Firebase Messaging

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send an `"interruption-level": "time-sensitive"` Push via Postman but no success so far...

All homework is done:

when asking for notification permeation.

```
authOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound, .timeSensitive]
```

in capabilites [image]

and the following is the body I am using to send notifications via the postman.

```
{
"to":"cQx9FO-p80gAjcA0OEcwXw:APA91bFfy2_tqVr-Acuii1RU6gCz5oZPJyReuU_Ms4gUGGur4m8N2pGTdZpBPNcagscZysomYsZvZ9h-fkLcyZYvBu5k-2BiadBM4J",
"priority":"high",
"content_available":true,
"interruption-level": "time-sensitive",
"badge": 6,

"notification":{
    "body":"Body",
    "title":"Title",
    "sound":"myTune.caf"
    },
}
```

I also tried other payloads different from the above but no success so far.

It works fine when the phone is not in focus mode.

but only the badge got an increment when the phone is in focus mode.

I thing i messed up with `"interruption-level": "time-sensitive"` in payload json.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using the [Legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). I don't think the Legacy supports the `interruption-level` payload. However, the [HTTP v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig) supports the new fields if they haven been added by APNs. Just add `"interruption-level": "time-sensitive"` under the `apns` property.

See also:

- [Is it available to pass interruption-level (iOS) through firebase cloud message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70814557/20447561)

Comment: I want to test it with `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` first...

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work because the Legacy API does not support the `interruption-level` payload.